# SQL can't create foreign key reference

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreign-keys

I am using this online compiler to compile my queries:

https://www.mycompiler.io/new/sql

This snippet shown here throws an error:

> error near foreign: syntax(1)

and I am unable to understand this

```
CREATE TABLE Course
(
    Ccode integer check(Ccode between 0 and 99) PRIMARY KEY,
    Course varchar(10) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Student 
(
    RollNo integer check(RollNo between 0 and 99999) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    CourseCode integer FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Course(Ccode),
    Mark1 integer check(Mark1 between 0 and 100),
    Mark2 integer check(Mark2 between 0 and 100)
);


INSERT INTO Student 
VALUES (1111, "Aries", 11, 100, 100);

SELECT * FROM Student;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using SQLite3 in the complier you added.

To solve the issue, move the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint after creating the variable.

```
CREATE TABLE Student 
(
    RollNo integer check(RollNo between 0 and 99999) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    CourseCode integer,
    Mark1 integer check(Mark1 between 0 and 100),
    Mark2 integer check(Mark2 between 0 and 100),
    FOREIGN KEY (CourseCode) REFERENCES Course(Ccode)
);
```